# Matriz em Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Queria que o meu programa executasse o seguinte.

```
        1 
      2 1
    3 2 1
5 4 3 2 1
```

E o mesmo para qualquer outro número.
Meu código está assim:

```
def matriz2(num_linhas):
    for linha in range(1,num_linhas+1):
        for i in range(linha,0,-1):
            print(i,end=' ')
        print()
```

Já está quase tudo mas falta os espaços antes dos números e não estou conseguindo fazer isso.

Answer (score 2):

Micro,

Uma possível solução seria você efetuar a impressão dos espaços em branco antes de seu segundo `for`, algo assim:

```
print((num_linhas -  linha) * "  ", end="")
```

Com isso você geraria os espaços a esquerda antes da impressão, veja que aqui também foi utilizado o `end` vazio para evitar a quebra de linha. Com isso, seu código ficaria assim:

```
def matriz2(num_linhas):
  for linha in range(1,num_linhas+1):
    print((num_linhas -  linha) * "  ", end="")
    for i in range(linha,0,-1):
      print(i,end=' ')
    print()
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/NarrowUnderstatedAccess

---

Você também pode criar uma variável e ir adicionando os números e espaços, efetuando o print apenas uma vez no `for` principal, nesse exemplo eu utilizei de `f-string` e também do `rjust` para gerar os espaços:

```
def matriz2(num_linhas):
  for linha in range(1,num_linhas+1):
    toPrint = ""
    for i in range(linha,0,-1):
      toPrint = f"{toPrint}{i} "
    print(toPrint.rjust(num_linhas * 2))
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/PettyGigaDifferences

---

Aqui uma outra forma de como isso pode ser feito, apenas como exemplo, pode ter certeza que existe outras formas de fazer:

```
def matriz(num_linhas):
  for linha in range(1, num_linhas+1):
    print("".join([str(num) + " " for num in range(num_linhas - (num_linhas - linha), 0, -1)]).rjust(num_linhas * 2))
```

Aqui eu utilizo do `join` para transformar uma lista em uma string e do `rjust` para colocar os espaços em branco, também uso o `str` para transformar o número em string.

> Veja esse outro exemplo online: https://repl.it/repls/OffshoreOutstandingFilesize